# Norm and Matrix

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, maxima-minima

Suppose that

$$
       \left( \begin{matrix}
        1 & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & -1 \\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$

calculate the maximum and minimum value of ||Ax|| on the sphere {x ∈ $R^3$: ||x|| = 1}.

I have $A^TA$ is symmetric then use it to get the max and min.But how to show the norm of $\mathbf Ax$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another method that I find easier (but specialized to this situation only) is using the eigenvalue method. You want to find the maximum and minimum of $||Ax||$. Note that this is the same as optimizing $||Ax||^2 = (Ax)\cdot (Ax) = (Ax)^T(Ax) = x^T A^T Ax$ which is a quadratic form with associated matrix $A^TA$. It is known that for a quadratic form and associated matrix $Q$ , the maximum value on the unit sphere is equal to the largest eigenvalue of $Q$ and the minimum value on the unit sphere is equal to the smallest eigenvalue of $Q$. If we calculate $A^TA$ we get
$$
       \left( \begin{matrix}
        2 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 2 & -1 \\
        1 & -1 & 2 \\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$
whose smallest eigenvalue is $0$ and largest eigenvalue is $3$. This is the minimum and maximum of $||Ax||^2$, so the minimum and maximum value of $||Ax||$ are $0$ and $\sqrt{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum is $0$; just take $x=\frac1{\sqrt3}(-1,1,1)$.

The maximum is $\sqrt3$. This can be determined applying the method of Lagrange multipliers. If $x=(a,b,c)$ is such that $\|x\|=1$, then $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$. On the other hand, $\|Ax\|^2=2+2(ab+ac-bc)$. Define $f(a,b,c)=2+2(ab+ac-bc)$ and define $g(a,b,c)=a^2+b^2+c^2$. Applying the method of Lagrange multipliers in order to find the maximum and the minimum of $f$, you are led to system of equations

$\displaystyle\left\{\begin{array}{l}b+c=2\lambda a\\a-c=2\lambda b\\
a-b=2\lambda c\\a^2+b^2+c^2=1\end{array}\right.$

This system has $8$ solutions. For $6$ of them, the value of $f$ at that point is $3$ and therefore the norm of $A$ times that point is $\sqrt3$. One such point is $\left(\frac{1}{6}
   \left(-3-\sqrt{3}\right),-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac
   {1}{6} \left(-3+\sqrt{3}\right)\right)$. At the remaining $2$ points, the value of $f$ is $0$.

Comment: Can you explain a little about the lagrange multipliers?

Comment: Sure. You will to solve a system with $4$ equations: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}=\lambda\frac{\partial g}{\partial a}$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}=\lambda\frac{\partial g}{\partial b}$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial c}=\lambda\frac{\partial g}{\partial c}$, and $g(a,b,c)=1$. These are the $4$ equations from my answer. The first $3$ of them are linear equations which depend upon $\lambda$. Since $(0,0,0)$ is not a solution of the fourth equation, you will have to determine for which $\lambda$ is it true that the system as non null solutions. That's when $\lambda=-1$ or $\lambda=\frac12$.